# use dictionary or map grooupby values to orginial dataframe in python

Tags: python, dictionary, enumerate

I have a dataframe with two columns, x and y, shown below.

```
X     Y
2     W
3     AA
6.5   W
8     W
23    AA
```

I Have applied a formula to find a total_weight for each group. Grouping by y values in this case. Found for group W total_weightt= 0.611 and for group AA total_weight = 0.258

Below is output I need?

```
X     Y     total_weight
2     W     0.611
3     AA    0.258
6.5   W     0.611
8     W     0.611
23    AA    0.258
```

Might involve using a dictionary, or some enumeration/iteration command.

See below code using Python 3
I have created the dataframe, and have calculated the total_weights for each group. 
How do i map it to the original dataframe??

```
data = {'x':[2,3,6.5,8,23], 'y':['W','AA','W','W','AA']}
df = DataFrame (data, columns=['x', 'y'])

grouped = df.groupby('y')
ni = len(grouped['x'])
n_weight = ni/len(df['x'])
ci = grouped['x'].mean()
c_weight = ci/df['x'].mean()
total_weight = n_weight * c_weight
print (total_weight)
```

Answer (score 1):

You have the correct answer to this in the title of your question: [`map`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.map.html):

```
df['total_weight'] = df['y'].map(total_weight)
```

Results:

```
      x   y  total_weight
0   2.0   W      0.258824
1   3.0  AA      0.611765
2   6.5   W      0.258824
3   8.0   W      0.258824
4  23.0  AA      0.611765
```